# Alignment in header

Tags: header-footer, memoir

Here is my minimal code:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[11pt,showtrims,openany]{memoir}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}

\setmainfont{Hoefler Text}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Gill Sans}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Andale Mono}


\addtopsmarks{headings}{}{
  \createmark{chapter}{left}{nonumber}{}{}
}
\pagestyle{headings} % activate changes
\makeevenhead{headings}{\thepage}{VOILÀ, C'EST DIT}{}
\makeoddhead{headings}{}{\leftmark}{\thepage}

\begin{document}

\mbox{}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage

\clearpage
Hello world.

\end{document}
```

I changed the Memoir default headers, but now the page number seems slightly lower than the centered text (and it causes a `overfull vbox` for the header.
[image]

```
Class memoir Warning: The material used in the headers is too large
(14.20879pt) for the given head height (13.6pt), it is recommended to
either increase the head height or redesign the header
(in both cases you will find help in the memoir manual). on input line 35.


Overfull \vbox (0.60878pt too high) has occurred while \output is active
```

I would like to avoid making the header higher, instead I'd like to fix the alignment problem (which I hope will make the required height smaller).

Comment: no the problem is the header does not have room for the accented A so that is pushing everything out of line, you need to add 1pt  to that (if you take 1pt off topmargin to compensate basically nothing else will move

Comment: @DavidCarlisle you're absolutely right! my bad. Thanks again I did not realize the problem could come from the accented A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the header does not have room for the accented A so that is pushing everything out of line, you need to add 1pt to `\headheight` . (If you take 1pt off `\topmargin` to compensate basically nothing else will move.)

Answer (score 2):

The `memoir` class has its own methods for setting the page parameters and it's best not to monkey with low level parameters such as `\headheight` and `\topmargin`.

You have to increase the head height, as told by the warning, so the command to use is `\setheadfoot`. Since we don't need to change the distance of the footer, we can do

```
\setheadfoot{14.2pt}{\footskip}
```

that will use the previous value for `\footskip`. Next `\checkandfixthelayout` should be issued.

```
\documentclass[11pt,showtrims,openany]{memoir}

\setheadfoot{14.2pt}{\footskip}
\checkandfixthelayout

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}

\setmainfont{Hoefler Text}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Gill Sans}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Andale Mono}


\addtopsmarks{headings}{}{
  \createmark{chapter}{left}{nonumber}{}{}
}
\pagestyle{headings} % activate changes
\makeevenhead{headings}{\thepage}{VOILÀ, C'EST DIT}{}
\makeoddhead{headings}{}{\leftmark}{\thepage}

\begin{document}

\mbox{}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage

\clearpage
Hello world.

\end{document}
```